# what is consensus in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Will anyone explains about consensus in hyperledger fabric and how it will work in fabric with a simple example. I have gone through so many websites but I didn't get any idea. please let me know anyone. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hii @rupesh, i found this good medium artical may this medium article help to understand hyperledger fabric 
 https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-does-hyperledger-fabric-works-cdb68e6066f5

Comment: I have gone through that link  but they didn't explain how the consensus will work clearly

Comment: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/txflow.html describes exactly how Fabric achieves consensus

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/fabric_model.html?highlight=consensus#consensus) high-level description, and the [transaction flow diagram](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/txflow.html) it links to.

The official documentation is always a good place to start...